# Bing Web Search API for Corporate bing search

Tags: bots, azure-cognitive-services, bing, bing-search

In our company when I navigate to https://www.bing.com/ I can login with my AAD account and able to perform a search specific to my Company. Meaning, I can filter my search results based on my organization.

I see something like "Show results from XyZ Corporation...."

This makes me think that we have Corporate version of Bing search or I might call it Enterprise Bing and some how its connected to my AAD account so it can fetch corporate search results for me.

However, I am trying to get similar search results by 'Bing Web Search API v7 [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices-bingsearch/bing-web-api-v7-reference)'

I see Web browser search results are different (when I'm logged in )that what I get using REST API.

If I search for 'holidays 2019' on web search I see some results but also see and option to filter them by my company name.

When I do same search using an API

`https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/search?q=holidays 2019`

I am definitely not sending user context, so I do get search results as if I was not logged in or same results I will get if I was not logged in.

Is there any way to get search results specific to my organization since I can do that on the browser I am trying to do the same programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution in your scenario is using [Bing Custom Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-custom-search/overview) as it gives you full control over the search results.

It allows you to specify a URL and whether to include subpages of the URL, add active entries to include results from specific websites or URLs, and much more!

You could also use [Microsoft Search in Bing](https://www.bing.com/business/explore) since that customizes results based on your logged in email AD which you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Do you think it can give me 'bing for enterprise' search results ?

Comment: I think what you are referring to as "bing for enterprise" is actually called **Microsoft Search in Bing**, which you can refer to in my updated answer.

Comment: Yes you are right Microsoft Search in Bing. Does that have an API ? I can get results from ?

Comment: If you're looking for an API to retrieve data, then I suggest the first solution in my answer which is **Bing Custom Search API** as it allows you to build your very own custom experience, but you can check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftsearch/connectors-overview) of Microsoft Search if you are looking to add connectors to your **Microsoft Search in Bing** experience and improve results in your organization.